# Ternary expression with "defined?" returns "expression" instead of value?

Tags: ruby, expression, ternary-operator

I'm pretty new to Ruby and Rails but even after searching stack overflow and google I couldn't find an answer to this.

I've got a simple Ruby shorthand if statement that should return an `integer` like so:

```
# in the context of this erb document `amount` is defined as 5.
@c = ( defined? amount ? amount : r( 1,4 ) )
```

`r()` is a custom helper function that returns a random number between *in this case* 1 and 4.

The way I intend this to work is that `if` `amount` is defined, then use the number defined as `amount`, `else` generate a random number between 1 and 4 and use that instead.

When printing out `@c` however Ruby outputs `expression` rather than a number.

What do I have to do to get this working as I intended and what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks for reading!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`defined?` is binding to `amount ? amount : r(1,4)` so it is equivalent to:

```
defined?(amount ? amount : r(1,4))
```

You probably want:

```
defined?(amount) ? amount : r(1,4)
```

Actually, odds are that `amount || r(1,4)`, or `amount.nil? ? r(1,4) : amount` would better match what you want, since I think you don't want this:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > defined?(amount)
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :002 > amount = nil
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :003 > defined?(amount)
 => "local-variable"
```

...in which case `@c` would be `nil` - the value of the defined variable.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! Obviously I have yet to learn some more of these basics but this has been super helpful `amount || r(x,y)` works exactly as I wanted and is all in less characters at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `||` operator in this case:

```
@c = amount || r (1,4)
```

In your code, the `defined?` method operates on `amount ? amount : r( 1,4 )` instead of just on `amount` as you intended. Also, the `defined?` operator probably doesn't do what you expect, have a look at this [blog entry](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/20/rubys-defined-operator/) to get an idea.

Comment: Thanks! That blog post was very enlightening, now I see what `defined?` is truly useful for!

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the null coalescing operator.  Try this:

```
@c = amount || r(1,4)
```

This code will assign amount to @c if amount is defined.  If not it will assign the result of r(1,4) to @c.

http://eddiema.ca/2010/07/07/the-null-coalescing-operator-c-ruby-js-python/